# PHP file inclusion on a required file

Tags: php

Here is an example directory structure:

```
-Root
    index.php
    -forms
        -form.php
    -include
        -include.php
```

In my index.php I am requiring the form.php

```
require_once('forms/form.php');
```

in my form.php I am requiring the include.php file. Which of the following is correct:

```
require_once('../include/include.php');
require_once('include/include.php');
```

My confusion comes from the idea that the form is being rendered in the index file, so would the files the form include need to be relative from the index (since that is where its rendered) or would it need to be relative to itself regardless of where it is rendered.

Comment: You can, very primitively, think of `require` as roughly the same as `eval(file_get_contents(...))` - it keeps the current context, which includes the current working directory.

Comment: Just don't include files like that... the moment your codebase reaches a certain degree of complexity, it'll be almost impossible to know what path to use, when and where. Use `set_include_path` and define a constant like `PROJECT_ROOT`, and use paths relative to that constant path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct is

`require_once('include/include.php');`

but it is beter to use absolute path:

`require_once(__DIR__.'/include/include.php');`

`__DIR__` works from PHP 5.3.0 up. In earler versions its equivalent was `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: `../include/include.php` Not correct! Because it goes from the index file! so the other one would be correct! Just test it and you will see it too

Comment: oops, sorry, haven't noticed that, thank you, I tried to be quicker than you :)

Comment: Thanks for including the better way to do it instead of just answering. I was able to get it to work using 'include/include.php'.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the magic constant [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), so you don't have to think about this, e.g.

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '../include/include.php');
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `require_once(__DIR__ . '../include/include.php');` since form.php is inside the forms directory which is a "sibling" to the include directory?